# Angular2+ QR code scanning from mobile browsers

Tags: android, ios, angular, windows-phone, qr-code

I'm doing some research on available ways of scanning a QR code using browsers on Android, iOS and possibly Windows Phone. The ideal solution would be to have a single Angular2+ responsive app that would work both on a mobile and a full sized computer screen. The whole app is supposed to be some kind of an inventory based on QR code stickers identifying items.

I've found a nice component https://github.com/goergch/angular2-qrscanner but it doesn't really work on any browser that I have on my phone(Firefox, Chrome, HTC Browser, Dolphin). And unfortunately there's no information if any mobile browsers are supported.

Does anyone know of a library/component that I could test for this purpose? Or should I forget about it and just build the system with Ionic(or perhaps NativeScript) and compile native apps?

Thank you in advance for all suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I have just got this working for Android after 2 days of debugging. Firstly, it needs to run over SSL in order for it to be able to access your deivce's camera (this is now a requirement in latest releases of both Chrome and FF on android). But essentially, the bug with it working on Android comes down to the dimensions of the canvas being used to generate an image from the camera's video feed. The values you pass in were actually used for the video element that you see on your device. However it is a hidden canvas element that is used to generate an image from the video stream and then analyse for a valid QR code. On mobile devices this canvas element was being blown up to huge dimensions, disregarding what you pass in to the component. So a scan using the passed in dimensions would only scan a tiny portion of the image rendered in the now giant canvas.

Fix is to ensure you pass in the values to the component template that can be rendered on the screen of a smartphone, so 320 x 480 for example. Then in your component css file force this restriction on the canvas element.

So, you component template should have something like the following:
...

```
<qr-scanner
(onRead)="captureScan($event)"
facing="environment"
[mirror]="true"
[stopAfterScan]="true"
[updateTime]="1000"
[canvasWidth]="320"
[canvasHeight]="480"
></qr-scanner>
```

...

And in your css file:
...

```
canvas {
    width: 320px !important;
    height: 480px !important;
}
```

..

This fix now works on Chrome & FF on android.